# VBA Code Not running fast as it was before ( This code never took time to run but now i dont know what happened)

Tags: excel, vba, performance

This is a code i used to extract data from a sheet to the All Salaries Master File. The code is taking a lot of time to run and this has never happened before until recently. I hope somebody can help me sort this issue out.

```
Sub UpdateDataFromMaster()

Dim filepath As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fullpath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim filedirectorypath As String
Dim varRecords As Variant
Dim pos As Integer
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error Resume Next

filepath = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 38)
gettempfolder = Environ("Temp")

fullpath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
filename = ThisWorkbook.Name
filedirectorypath = Left(fullpath, Len(fullpath) - Len(filename) - 1)
pos = InStrRev(filedirectorypath, "\")
rootdirectorypath = Left(filedirectorypath, pos - 1)
filepath = rootdirectorypath & "\" & "All Salaries Master File.xlsm"
destpath = gettempfolder & "\" & "All Salaries Master File.xlsm"

If Len(Dir$(destpath)) > 0 Then
     Kill destpath
End If

Call fso.CopyFile(filepath, destpath)

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
''Using Query function to fetch data
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [All sheet$]"
connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & destpath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1""; Mode=Read;"
cn.Open connstr
Set rs = cn.Execute(CommandText:=strSQL)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
cn.Close

If Len(Dir$(destpath)) > 0 Then
    Kill destpath
End If

Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0
    
Application.StatusBar = "Data Updated"
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Which bit takes the time?

Comment: Try stepping trhough the code and check whic line is taking lot of time

Comment: The bit to fetch data quickly. As i run the run code it takes about 2=3 minutes to execute

Answer (score 1):

I would check the following:

- Perhaps your **All Salaries Master File.xlsm** file has gotten bigger. When Excel tries to process thousands of rows, things get slow.
- Perhaps your VBA workbook has gotten bigger (i.e. **ThisWorkbook** with **Source** sheet). When workbooks become several MB in size, they can become slow.
- Perhaps your disk drive is low on free space. Check drive space represented by your **gettempfolder**, and any other drives involved.

Comment: Hello Dear, I tried all the above still this code takes time to run even when i recreated the master file and it size reduced from 8 mb to 3 mb

Comment: - It looks like all your paths (source/destination/temp) are on the same drive, so it should be quick. However, if any of your paths are on network drives, then it may be a network problem.
 - If one of your folders (e.g. **destpath**) contains a lot of files, it may slow the access. 
 - You may have a **Windows Scheduled Task** or **Windows Service** that is constantly trying to access one of those files. 
 - You may have antivirus software (e.g. **Windows Defender**) that is constantly scanning one of those files.